# DataFrame: fillna() with running sum of valid values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working a Pandas Dataframe, that looks like this:

```
0   Data
1   
2   
3   
4   5
5   
6   
7   
8   21
9   
10  2
11  
12  
13  
14  
15
```

I'm trying to fill the blank with next valid values by: df.fillna(method='backfill'). This works, but then I need to add the previous valid value to the next valid value, from the bottom up, such as:

```
0   Data
1   28
2   28
3   28
4   28
5   23
6   23
7   23
8   23
9   2
10  2
11  
12  
13  
14  
15
```

I can get this to work by looping over it, but is there a method within pandas that can do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reverse the df, then [`fillna(0)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas.Series.fillna) and then [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and reverse again:

```
In [12]:

df = df[::-1].fillna(0).cumsum()[::-1]
df
Out[12]:
    Data
0   28.0
1   28.0
2   28.0
3   28.0
4   23.0
5   23.0
6   23.0
7   23.0
8    2.0
9    2.0
10   0.0
11   0.0
12   0.0
13   0.0
14   0.0
```

here we use slicing notation to reverse the df, then replace all `NaN` with `0`, perform `cumsum` and reverse back

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way to do that : `df.sum()-df.fillna(0).cumsum()`